# Removing sand-blasting residue from window glass

Tags: windows, cleaning, glass, paint-removal

I had some surface paint removed from my patio floor and some of the sand ended up on the surface of the window near by. It almost looks like it stuck to the glass. Is there any nice way to remove these sand particles without damaging the glass surface?

Comment: Sandblasting is used to make "frosted" glass. I have a feeling that won't be so easy to "remove".

Comment: If that sand does not wash off with a hose and brush then you will be replacing the glass.

Comment: You should contact who sand blasted and ask them to come out and address. If you try cleaning on your own, they might claim you did it , made it worse by not properly cleaning it, or it was already like that. Also, take lots of pictures of the issue as it stands now

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't be asking if it just wiped off, which it would if it was just a little bit of low-energy dust caught by the wind.

This tells me the glass was hit by high-energy sand particles, i.e. caught overspray from the blasting proper.  Sandblasting damages glass, and your contractor should've known that.  He has etched the glass (by roughening its surface, removing the gloss, which sandblasting does quite sincerely). I don't believe it can be recovered, and will need to be replaced.